# Advise on ROS move_base costmap footprint not connected error

Tags: ros, motion-planning, navigation

I'm using ROS indigo in my project and all the nodes and visualisation (Rviz) seems to be functional when I launch the program using roslaunch. Here are the sensors used in the scooter:

- Hokuyo Lidar
- Phidgets Encoder

However, when I start moving the scooter (the robot) using the joystick, the scooter will move physically, but in Rviz, the object detected by the lidar moves to the scooter, instead of the scooter moving in the map. Furthermore, the costmap obstacles will get smeared as I continue to move the scooter forward. Where could I have missed out?

Here are the node connections:

[image]

A screenshot of the tf tree:

[image]

EDIT:
When I did *roswtf*, it shows that the robot footprint is disconnected, though the rqt graph shows otherwise. Here is the log of it:

```
Beginning test of your ROS graph. These may take a while...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules
running tf checks, this will take a second...
... tf checks complete

Online checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fone, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
* /rqt_gui_py_node_646:
  * /statistics
  * /tf_static
* /amcl:
  * /tf_static
* /rviz_1476945491120458509:
  * /tf_static
  * /map_updates
* /move_base
  * /tf_static
  * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/obstacles
  * /move_base/cancel
* /robot_pose_publisher
  * /tf_static


Found 1 error(s).

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /move_base->/move_base (/move_base/global_costmap/footprint)
 * /move_base->/move_base (/move_base/local_costmap/footprint)
```

Please advise on the possible ways that I can undertake to debug this issue.

Comment: Seems like the fixed-frame in rviz is not "map" Hard to figure out the root cause with information you provided. Please provide your rviz setting as well.

Comment: The fixed frame in Rviz was set to map, here is a screenshot of rviz: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYTr7.png

Comment: How does Encoder effect /odom? Since map is fixed, and /odom, /base_link stuck there, looks like the encoder data doesn't change any transformation.

Comment: The encoder actually does provide the odom of the scooter. When i tested out rviz with only the tfs checked, the odom and base_link does move accordingly. But when I overlay the static map, the map will move instead of the robot footprint moving on the map. The same thing happens when I overlay the local costmap. Is it possible that some frame settings within the node has been wrongly set?

Comment: check/uncheck visible items in rviz should not change tf tree. However, according to your description, you might have to check whether the tf tree changes when you check/uncheck static map and cost map.

Comment: Another weird thing, your amcl node didn't listen to /odom, then how did it work? To simplify debugging, trying to disable amcl first might be another way to go.

Comment: When I tried disabling amcl and move _base, the base_link tf will move with respect to the odom tf. However, when I re-enable the amcl w/o movebase, with the map as the fixed frame, i noticed that the map tf moves with the odom tf, though the map tf should be fixed. I also ensured that the amcl global frame id is map, odom frame id is odom, and baselink id as base_id.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Photon. On stack exchange, it is better to edit your question to add information requested in comments, rather than adding more comments. Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. If all of the information needed to answer the question is contained within it, the comments can be tidied up (deleted), which can happen at any time.

Comment: What was the outcome of this? I am facing a similar issue.